# angular2 -click-button-to-highlight -next-previous-div

Tags: angular

Need one help

Here I am trying to do in angular 2

1.Show card one below another 
2.first hello div(Hello) will be active 
3.on next button click second div can be highlight and then so on.. 
4.Now suppose div four (Hello 4) and active div, now if I click on previous button it should highlight the previous div means card three (hello 3) and so on..

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should achieve your purpose through the usage of `*ngIf` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html). Basically, you need to set the bounded variables true/false in your component inside the `(click)` event of Angular. Then the `*ngIf` shows/hides/activates/deactivates/highligths the elements.